# Rails 5 : AJAX variable undefined on ajax:error / ajax:success events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `form_with` that calls a controller that responds in JSON. I would like to run javascript (handle errors, ...) during an event `ajax:success` or `ajax:error`.

I followed the Rails documentation. Unfortunately, the variables in my events are `undefined`. Only `e` are set.

Form:

```
<%= form_with url: contact_path, scope: 'message', id: 'new_message' do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'validate' %>
        <%= f.label :name, 'Nom' %>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'validate' %>
        <%= f.label :email, 'Email' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <%= f.telephone_field :phone, class: 'validate' %>
        <%= f.label :phone, 'Téléphone' %>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <%= f.text_field :website, class: 'validate' %>
        <%= f.label :website, 'Site Web' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'materialize-textarea validate' %>
        <%= f.label :content, 'Message' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s6">
        <%= recaptcha_tags %>
      </div>
      <div class="col s6">
        <%= button_tag class: 'btn primary waves-effect waves-light right' do %>
            Envoyer
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if verify_recaptcha(model: @message) && @message.valid?
        MessageMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
        format.json { render json: @message, status: :created }
      else
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

CoffeeScript:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#new_message").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    console.log(xhr);
  ).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    console.log(xhr);
```

Result:

```
undefined  message.self-5eda06948d26dade035273a7f168828c2cb1852e26937c49f50da7ca2532ad72.js:4:14


Started POST "/contact" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-13 17:19:17 +0200
Processing by MessagesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aBxh+eJedXw0WifdUXFAlgH0gWxNpiDQa2J3hdJayC/wBaccIxNSVK4pycYwu9XMb1s2/r9S8+FteRFoocdrZQ==", "messages"=>{"name"=>"", "email"=>"", "phone"=>"", "website"=>"", "content"=>""}, "g-recaptcha-response"=>"03AOPBWq9SEfWUxzdyMRMdd0p65vonbGjNjA_mhCA07vfoXyA6_nEVn220Ot5HU90_KpQv6ziii0VCoa1hZosUcsARL7DuJbFHA2kt_NBHvnURmPpKR0SMq0OfulzJokvobdu9t1z33Uby3oTAtTgEAEmxX6yDc_yuwmqHXAjh5SL0bhAyD6AF2wAN8me7fMKMULu_DS5KtLgwJjK8B2TmvGydn0neHDWcfSbDKP7WRP-RQQePc9hDcOCbUFoVrW2kfpg3p4OV-hWiV4q6-HBRZK3A1mcj5rJZd_zBe3v-yx6LHAXB2Bsb9Uc", "button"=>""}
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2701ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 856.3ms)
```

Comment: why your url form is `contact_path` ? you want `message_path` or not?

Comment: Oh thank you. I forgot to rename my route. But my controller is call. This is not the worry.

Comment: what you get in your console?

Comment: What documentation were you following?

Comment: @Ahmad: Thine one : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

@inye: `undefined`

I use another strategy that is to respond in javascript to work around the problem. (https://github.com/mohitjain/ajaxified_scaffold/blob/master/app/views/products/create.js.erb)

Comment: And the server console? (where you start with `rails server`)

Comment: Add in main post

Comment: You have a invalid `message`, maybe because all message parameters are blank. You have validator to `Message`? or database restriction in our messages table? . You can debug and put a `byebug` before render and see `@message.errors`. Also you can add `ajax:complete` to debug in browser console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using the rails-ujs adapter, according to this [Rails Edge Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#rails-ujs-event-handlers):

> Signature of calls to UJS's event handlers has changed. Unlike the
>   version with jQuery, all custom events return only one parameter:
>   event. In this parameter, there is an additional attribute detail
>   which contains an array of extra parameters.

I'd suggest taking a look at your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` and find out which ujs adapter you are currently using. `//= require rails-ujs` is the new default.

Take a look at the example provided in the guide. You can extract `data`, `status`, and `xhr` in the following manner.

```
document.body.addEventListener('ajax:success', function(event) {
  var detail = event.detail;
  var data = detail[0], status = detail[1],  xhr = detail[2];
})
```

Another alternative is to to use `jquery_ujs` which was the default prior to Rails 5.1 and has a signature more like you were expecting.